# Trying to return database rows to be used in a PickerView

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Hi Im new to ios and programming in general.

I am trying to use a pickerview that loads the options from a CoreData entity.

not sure how to do it this is what I have so far but the line "return output[row]" arent right. Can I please have help to how to make this work ? thanks

```
//
//  storeSelect.swift
//  assignment2_18094969
//
//  Created by James Duncombe on 25/1/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 James Duncombe. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import CoreData

class storeSelect: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

    //outlet for the pickerview widget
    @IBOutlet weak var picker: UIPickerView!

    var output : [StoreTable] = []

    //var to store the pickerview data (change this to suit the db later)
    //var pickerDataSource = ["Narellan", "Camden", "Campbelltown", "Liverpool", "Parramatta"]; //ignore this atm

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        output = retrieveRows()

        self.picker.dataSource = self
        self.picker.delegate = self

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return output.count;
    }


    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return output[row]
    }

    func retrieveRows() -> [StoreTable]{
        let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "StoreTable", in: managedObjectContext)
        let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>()
        request.entity = entityDescription // get the table drinkTable
        var storeObjs = [StoreTable]()

        do{
            try storeObjs = managedObjectContext.fetch(request) as! [StoreTable] }
        catch {
            //show some error msg
        }


        return storeObjs;
    }
    //output variable stores PizzaTable data and displays using the retrieve method



    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

Comment: the error is cannot convert expression type StoreTable to String?

Comment: storable is an entity right?

Comment: yes StoreTable is the entity

Comment: what are its properties? does it have a name?

Comment: Only has 'name' as an attribute (string).

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
   return "abcd"
}
```

The above function should return a **String**. Not a coredata entity. If the entity **StoreTable** has a `String` property, for e.g let us assume it has a name which is of `String` type, then the function should be

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
   return return output[row].name
}
```